# Oracle Connectivity using ODBC

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc, excel-2007

I have a table say TableA in Oracle database with 2 million record and 52 Columns.

I am trying to fetch all this data to MS excel 2007 using ODBC driver against which I have to do Pivot.

Now I have two questions to be asked , which is as follows..

Problem 1 ) sometime (not always)  I am getting error while fetching the records as "select less data or close other application "

Problem 2) every time data get inserted into my TableA I have to refresh my Pivot for doing that i have to fetch again entire data again to Excel .. Is there any ways to fetch only incremental data without disturbing existing data in MS Excel Pivot

I am using Oracle 10g and MS excel 2007

Comment: If you're fetching the data in order to create a pivot table then maybe you can apply some aggregation in your SQL query such that you fetch fewer records?  Eg. if your pivot table shows sums or averages then you can apply those calculations in your SQL.  Also, do you need to fetch all 52 columns?  That's a lot of data if you have 2M rows.

Comment: Hi Tim,
you are right but even though i m allowed to remove some columns but i cant aggregate data... because User need to drill down to the lowest possible level, in that case my number of rows remains the same...

Comment: Then I think you might need a different tool given the size of your dataset.  Have you looked at PowerPivot?  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx